# Client side file processing - Convert the uploaded excel to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html

Is it possible to read and process a user uploaded excel file using plain javascript?

I would like to get the file contents In JSON format.

Comment: Before your edit you had one question. Now you have changed it, it has become two questions. The first of those is still a duplicate of the reading the file question. The other is "Having read an Excel file into a JavaScript string, how do I convert the data into JSON?" which would be better asked as a completely separate question (after you've done some research to see if you can figure out that part for yourself).

Comment: Sure, will add a separate question after some more research.